# RSA key format is not supported in python

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I want to encrypt the plain text with the public key I have. To do this, I wrote the code using the pycryptodome module as follows.

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64decode,b64encode

key = '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\n\'

plain = 'lee'
keyPub = RSA.importKey(key)
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(RSA.import_key(keyPub))
print(cipher.encrypt(plain))
```

However, the following error occurs in `keyPub = RSA.importKey(key)`

```
RSA key format is not supported
```

How can I fix the following errors?

Comment: That doesn't look like an RSA key to me.  What format is it supposed to be?  The documentation tells you what formats RSA.importKey supports/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an RSA public key in X.509/SPKI format, encoded as hex string, which can be verified online e.g. at https://lapo.it/asn1js/. However, the `\n\` at the end must be removed.
[`importKey`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.import_key) expects binary (or PEM encoded) data for this fromat, i.e. the key must be hex decoded. The imported key can be used *directly* when instantiating the [`PKCS1_v1_5`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/pkcs1_v1_5.html#pkcs-1-v1-5-encryption-rsa) object (i.e. the second call with `import_key` is not needed).

The following code works:

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA

key = '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'

plain = b'lee'
keyPub = RSA.import_key(bytes.fromhex(key))
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPub)
print(cipher.encrypt(plain).hex())
```